# Large intergers (long) in angular http response are rounded off

Tags: angular, typescript, http, casting

I am calling a web service that returns

```
[
    {
        "product_id": 4253579243953800463,
        "timestamp": 1525107472,
        "event_type": "PRODUCT_VIEW",
        "event_count": 1
    },
    {
        "product_id": 788410946016999754,
        "timestamp": 1525107472,
        "event_type": "PRODUCT_VIEW",
        "event_count": 1
    }
]
```

I have coded a service in my angular code that makes a call to this backend service

```
  getLastRecommendations(): Observable<UserProductEvent[]> {
   return this.http.get<UserProductEvent[]>(url, HTTP_OPTIONS)
  }
```

I see that the response the product id is of type long, and its value is greater than Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER in javascript, so I want to force the product id to be treated as string.
otherwise the values are rounded off to

```
[
    {
        "product_id": 4253579243953800700,
        "timestamp": 1525107472,
        "event_type": "PRODUCT_VIEW",
        "event_count": 1
    },
    {
        "product_id": 788410946016999800,
        "timestamp": 1525107472,
        "event_type": "PRODUCT_VIEW",
        "event_count": 1
    }
]
```

I tried changing the type of product_id to string in my typescript interface declaration but it still does not work.

How can I force typescript/javascript to consider the field as string?

Could anyone please help?

```
export interface UserProductEvent {
    product_id: string;
    timestamp: number;
    event_type: string;
    event_count: number;
}
```

and I can't get the backend changed. :(

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Best way to deal with very large Long numbers in Ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525783/best-way-to-deal-with-very-large-long-numbers-in-ajax)

Comment: If you don't have any way to alter the back end response, then you will unfortunately need to get the response as text instead of json and use your own alternative to `JSON.parse()`.  If you are being fast and loose you can probably use some regular expression to encase the long strings of digits in quotation marks before passing it to the standard `JSON.parse()`, but that is fragile.  Or you can find an [existing parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/lossless-json) and use that.