# Angular convert ids of http request from long to string

Tags: json, angular, http

In my Backend I have IDs as long. Sadly Angular or better Javascript does not like long ids very much and rounds large numbers. Since that is not optimal for IDs I need to convert it from long to string before parsing it into a json object:

```
this.http.get<Player>(this.getUrl() + '/' + id);
```

My Player class:

```
export class Player {
   id: string;
   name: string;
}
```

How can I covert the ids to string before making a object from them?

This is the backend answer:

> { "id": **12345**, "name": "Test" }

This is what I need to convert it to before converting to an object:

> { "id": **"**12345**"**, "name": "Test" }

Comment: use a pipe&map to alter the response

Comment: You could use RxJS `map` operator to transform the response: `this.http.get(this.getUrl() + '/' + id).pipe(map(p => ({...p, id: String(p.id)}) as Player))`.

Comment: I think a this point it is to late, because it was already mapped to an object and the ID was rounded already :/

Comment: @julien-100000: What exactly do you mean by "rounded"? What is the expected value and what is it rounded to?

Comment: Expected: 9180021352890858370, Actual: 9180021352890858000
This is why: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5525783/best-way-to-deal-with-very-large-long-numbers-in-ajax

Answer (score 1):

Use pipe and map to alter the response;

```
this.http.get(this.getUrl() + '/' + id).pipe(map((player) => {
  player.id = ""+player.id;
  return player;
}));
```

Comment: I think the problem is that it is not late to do this after the conversion to an object, because then the id is already rounded :/

Comment: then don't typecast it to <Player> directly into the get function, do it after the pipe map

Answer (score 0):

you can use `toString()` method

```
this.http.get<Player>(this.getUrl() + '/' + id).pipe(map((player) => {
   player.id = player.id.toString();
   return player;
}));
```

Comment: I think the problem is that it is not late to do this after the conversion to an object, because then the id is already rounded :/